# Conditional trait bounds possible?

Tags: rust, traits

The trait bound in `baz` is unnecessarily strong for when `flag=true`, in which case we only require `Foo`.

I would like to have that `baz` can accept `where T: Foo` and *only* enforce the `Bar` bound when `flag=false`.

```
trait Foo {}
trait Bar: Foo {}

fn foo<T>(t: T) where T: Foo {}
fn bar<T>(t: T) where T: Bar {}

fn baz<T>(t: T, flag: bool) 
where T: Bar 
{
    if flag {
        foo(t);
    } else {
        bar(t);
    }
}
```

Changing the bound to `where T: Foo` will of course not compile:

> `bar(t)`
>
> .........^ the trait `Bar` is not implemented for `T`

Introducing a new function `quux` which can be called by `!Bar` types is probably the solution I'll have to accept.
But is there any way both `Bar` and `!Bar` types could both access a single function `baz`?

A solution which involves a runtime panic if `flag=false` and `T: !Bar` is acceptable.

Comment: I can't see how splitting this up in two functions is "breaking the API". If the `baz()` function already exists with the `Foo` trait bound, adding a new function with a `Bar` bound shouldn't break any existing code.

Comment: In fact it exists in the form with the `Bar` trait bound, I've just pasted the `Foo` form of the trait bound which doesn't compile.

Comment: So you'd like to _loosen_ the trait bound on `baz`, from the current `Bar` to the `Foo` shown in the question (which doesn't compile)? And by "breaking" the API you mean breaking it up into two functions, not breaking as in making a backward-incompatible change?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit the question so hopefully this becomes clearer.

Comment: "without breaking the API" is still confusing because adding a new function is not a breaking change. Did you mean "changing the API" or "breaking **up** the API"?

Comment: Apologies, I've removed the phrase now. Hopefully should make sense after latest edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I think what you're asking for is not possible in current Rust, but will be possible with specialization. Specialization might allow you to define a new trait and implement it to do one thing for `T: Foo` and another for `T: Bar` (which is currently not allowed due to overlap). Then `baz` would trivially call the method from that trait which would resolve to the right thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are asking for is not possible in current Rust, as it requires [specialization](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html). With specialization as proposed by the [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md), `baz` could be implemented using a helper trait with a blanket implementation for `T: Foo` and a specialized implementation for `T: Bar`.

Sadly, specialization does not appear to be a priority at this time (being superseded by even more important features like const generics), so it will take a while for it to be implemented and stabilized. Still, for the fun of it, here is an implementation based on specialization as found on current nightly:

```
#![feature(specialization)]

trait Foo {}
trait Bar: Foo {}

fn foo<T: Foo>(_t: T) -> &'static str {
    "foo"
}
fn bar<T: Bar>(_t: T) -> &'static str {
    "bar"
}

trait Dispatch {
    fn dispatch(self, flag: bool) -> &'static str;
}

impl<T: Foo> Dispatch for T {
    default fn dispatch(self, flag: bool) -> &'static str {
        // there is no way to call bar(self) here, so we can only assert the flag is true
        assert!(flag);
        foo(self)
    }
}

impl<T: Bar> Dispatch for T {
    fn dispatch(self, flag: bool) -> &'static str {
        if flag {
            foo(self)
        } else {
            bar(self)
        }
    }
}

fn baz<T: Foo>(t: T, flag: bool) -> &'static str {
    t.dispatch(flag)
}

fn main() {
    struct A;
    impl Foo for A {}
    assert_eq!(baz(A, true), "foo");
    //baz(A, false) panics

    struct B;
    impl Foo for B {}
    impl Bar for B {}
    assert_eq!(baz(B, true), "foo");
    assert_eq!(baz(B, false), "bar");
}
```

(Compilable code in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=641041c1f053956c488d04d0a7585a80).)